# What can cause blurry dots using Sigma Sony FE 24 70mm f/2.8?

Tags: troubleshooting, sigma, blur, sony-alpha

I use the Sony A7C with the Sigma Sony FE 24 70mm f/2.8 lens. The lens itself is clean from on the front and on the back and I don't see any dust on the camera sensor aswell. Do you have any ideas ?

I think the settings were something like ISO 250, F6, SS 200

PS: picture is cropped and zoomed in order to show better the small blurred area which are concerning me

[image]

Comment: Make few more photos and check if you have the same dots on the same place

Comment: @RomeoNinov, it doesn't seem to appears on every photos from the session, I'll try to do some test at home

Comment: Looks like sensor dirt. More visible on clear pictures, with a closed diaphragm. Shoot at something very clear (clouds, white wall, or your PC display filled with white), with a very closed diaphragm (f/22 or more), with the camera out of focus. It should show up a the same place in multiple shots, even with different lenses.

Comment: @xenoid thank you a lot for the tip ! I'll try that, if this test conclude positive. Should I use a air pump (made for cleaning camera) in order to clean my sensor ?

Comment: Yes, the air pump is the first move and is enough in many cases. Otherwise don't panic, it won't be visible in most shots, and isn't very hard to fix in post-prod.

Comment: +1 for @xenoid's comment. If this is sensor dirt, it will also appear in the same place in your images, regardless of whether your 24-70 lens is at the wide or tele end. Might be stating the obvious, but worth being explicit.

Comment: Sensor dust is probably the first possibility, but spots on the rear element of your lens can also show up that way. Not so much with the front element, though....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like sensor dirt.

This is more visible on clear pictures, with a closed diaphragm.

To check, shoot at something very clear (clouds, white wall, or your PC display filled with white), with a very closed diaphragm (f/22 or more), with the camera out of focus. Stains should show up at the same place in multiple shots, even with different lenses(*).

Very often a shot of air blower is enough.

Otherwise no need to panic if the sensor is a bit dirty, it won't show in most pictures, and is easy to fix in post production. When this becomes really annoying, then it's time to try your hand with a sensor cleaning kit or a visit to the service shop.

(*) The most efficient lens for this is a pinhole lens (very often DYI). Its equivalent f-number is close to 200 and this makes sensor dirt very visible.